# How do people respond to auditory warning signals?

Tags: perception, human-factors, reaction-time, hearing

I am working on a literature review of total reaction time to an auditory alert, in a transport context.  All of the literature I can find about perception-response times are in the context of visual obstacles while driving, but in this case I'm interested in perception-response times to auditory-only warning signals (and not specifically drivers).

These are the best sources on PRT I have found so far, all to visual stimuli:
Olson, P.L. & Sivak, M. (1986) Perception-response time to unexpected roadway hazards.   Human Factors, 28, 96-99.
Olson, P., "Driver Perception Response Time," SAE Technical Paper 890731, 1989, doi:10.4271/890731.
Summala, H. (2000). Brake Reaction Times and Driver Behavior Analysis. Transportation Human Factors, 2(3), 217-226.

What are the equivalents examining perception-response time to auditory stimuli?

Answer (score 3):

Often, very similar phenomena have different names when studied in different modalities, because they are studied by different communities. That's why searching for [perception response times + auditory](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=perception-response%20times%20auditory) doesn't yield great results (Although I did find [1] this way).

Something else to try, is to pick a highly cited paper that you did find, and then search within paper citing it for relevant terms. I started from Olson's 2000 paper which you mentioned, and searched for "auditory" within citing papers, and quickly found [2] and [3].

You can also look for other papers by the same authors - people tend to keep studying similar questions for a while, and often keep using the same methodologies.

---

[1] Cheng, B., Hashimoto, M., & Suetomi, T. (2002). Analysis of driver response to collision warning during car following. JSAE review, 23(2), 231-237.

[2] Fitch, G. M., Blanco, M., Morgan, J. F., & Wharton, A. E. (2010, September). Driver braking performance to surprise and expected events. In Proceedings of the Human Factors and Ergonomics Society Annual Meeting (Vol. 54, No. 24, pp. 2075-2080). SAGE Publications.

[3] Cao, Y., Mahr, A., Castronovo, S., Theune, M., Stahl, C., & Müller, C. A. (2010, February). Local danger warnings for drivers: The effect of modality and level of assistance on driver reaction. In Proceedings of the 15th international conference on Intelligent user interfaces (pp. 239-248). ACM.

Comment: Yep, I found these too!  But they're focused on drivers who also have visual warnings, which is not particularly applicable.